# loop, bug in validation [Python]

Tags: python, validation, loops

I am trying to validate my python script:

```
def DOBSearch():
loop = True
while loop == True:
    try:
        DOBsrch = int(input("Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: "))
        for row in BkRdr:
            DOB = row[6]
            day,month,year = DOB.split("/")
            if DOBsrch == int(month): 
                print("W")
                surname = row[0]
                firstname = row[1]
                print(firstname, " ",surname)
                addrsBk.close
                loop = False
            else:
                print("1 That was an invalid choice please try again.")
    except:
        print("That was an invalid choice please try again.")
```

However when I try to test the script I find there is a bug/error as I get the following outputs:

```
     Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: ergase
That was an invalid choice please try again.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 34
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
1 That was an invalid choice please try again.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 234567
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 02
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 02
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 02
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02:
```

here is the CSV file:

```
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com
Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196 678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com
Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256 728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk
Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458 288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk
Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569 276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com
Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675 662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com
```

Comment: the `else` from the `if DOBsrch == int(month): ` seems misplaced

Comment: where would u recommend, the try except checks the type of value e.g. int, string etc... WHilst the else makes sure it is a valid choice of month?

Comment: Try inspecting the exception that is raised. And generally, you'll want to avoid using plain `except` blocks, but instead specify the exception types you know can be raised from your code. If you just catch everything, you can hide errors that you weren't expecting.

Comment: Can someone please post a answer or alternative solution

Comment: Do you know which `print` statement is actually being printed? The one under `else` or the one under `except`?

Comment: Pls c the edit to the question

Comment: Add the definition of `BkRdr` please

Comment: @TimCastelijns that is the csv file reader

Comment: What data does it represent? You loop over it so it's important to know

Comment: @TimCastelijns pls c the edit